# Font not reflecting proper font size

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in my database that uses several forms to generate a PDF document.  The issue I am having is that every time the database is moved or copied by users, the font is no longer properly sized.

It is set to Arial Narrow, Bold, 16 font. To 'solve' this I just adjust the font in any way, so if I simply set the font back to Arial Narrow, the font goes back to the proper size, even though the font size hasn't changed. Same result if I turn bold off and then back on, the font goes back to the proper size even though in the toolbar it never changes from 16 font.

Obviously with a form containing 7 subforms this solution is unreasonable since I have to do this every couple of days. I know I could resolve this programmatically using vba, however I feel like it shouldn't be happening to begin with.

I apologize if this has been answered somewhere previously, this issue is hard enough to explain let alone search for in google.

**Update:**

The following is my code which kind of works, I have this set to happen on load, which fixes the main form, then you must close the form and open it again for the subforms to be affected.  I assume they are being corrected the first time however for some time are not adjusting until the form is reloaded.

I have attempted to refresh, and repaint the subforms as once they are updated however I can't seem to find a way to make this happen automatically. Also it isn't just when the database is moved, if you close and open the database that form's font becomes oversized again.

```
Public Function FixFontSize(frm As Form)
On Error Resume Next

    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In frm.Controls
        Select Case ctl.ControlType
            Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acLabel, acCommandButton
                ctl.FormName = "tahoma" 
                ctl.FontName = "arial narrow"
            Case acSubform
                Call FixFontSize(ctl.Name)
        End Select
    Next ctl

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant solution I imagine is write a function that loops through the controls on a form and uses the `FontSize`, `FontName` etc properties and set them to what you want

Added a simple example of looping through the controls on the form.

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If c.ControlType = acTextBox Or c.ControlType = acLabel Then
        c.FontSize = 16
    End If
Next
```

There are more than `acTextBox` and `acLabel` with `.Font` Properties but you should be able to customize it to your needs.

Also including a link to MSDN that lists all the control types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224135%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: While I do appreciate this answer, I was more so hoping to understand why this could be happening to begin with.  It only happens on this one particular form, no other forms are affected by this.

Comment: Also, wouldn't that cause errors on all non-text controls?

Comment: My first guess to why its happening is that the fonts might not have been available on the different users computer?  You mentioned that the database gets moved.  Another solution/way to diagnose if its related to the users opening is to have them open copies of the front end of the database and see if the original changes ever.  If it doesn't anymore than most likely related to someone who is opening it without the font or something of that sort.  But this is merely a guess

Comment: You can have an `IF` statement to filter out control types that don't have the `.Font...` properties.  I will add the appropriate information

Comment: I have created a function that will do this on load for the moment. Regarding the testing to see if the users can open the main front end. Once it has been created and adjusted, it would allow anyone to open it and it would work fine, however if you so much as copied the front end and then pasted it into the same folder, when you open the copied front end it would revert back to the old oversized font. Even though the font properties showed the correct type and size.  This would happen to all users, including myself.